# create outbuond smtp server using smtp-server nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, smtp-server

I was trying to create a SMTP server using nodejs module "smtp-server" and referred this: http://nodemailer.com/extras/smtp-server/. When I tried to send mail using nodemailer to server it went properly but when I tried to send mail to gmail account it was never receiver there.

I set up dkim and SPF for my smtp server and checked them using online checkers and my code is same as before as I mentioned here: [Could not send mail to users email using my smtp server on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73237924/could-not-send-mail-to-users-email-using-my-smtp-server-on-website)

**Assumption:**
For sending mail to gmail account I assumed that server automatically redirects mail to gmail server if I put my gmail account in "to:" section of message. Later I studied multiple article and found that there is some thing like outbounding which is used to redirect mail to other server. Kindly tell me how can I set it up for smtp-server module.